# Hive Timestamp aggregation

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two hive tables, in which one table is updating an hourly basic by Java API team (they are calling and storing it into hive `table1`). And now I have to aggregate the latest data and store it into another table called `table2` (data which are loaded newly,because old data have been aggregated and stored). For that I have used the query below:

```
set maxtime = select max(lastactivitytimestamp) from table2;
insert into table2 select * from table1 where lastactivitytimestamp > unix_timestamp('${hivevar:maxtime}');
```

I am not getting any result. But when I give the timestamp value manually I am getting data, like below:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 where lastactivitytimestamp > unix_timestamp('2014-08-18 15:23:26.754');
```

Is it possible to pass dynamic values in `unix_timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the upper commas from the unix_timestamp() function, like this:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 where lastactivitytimestamp > unix_timestamp(${hivevar:maxtime});
```